# Whats the alternative to the getdate() function in C++4.3.2?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

This runs in Turbo C++, but doesn't work on newer versions of C++. Any alternatives to this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>

main()
{
   struct date d;
   getdate(&d);
   printf("Current system date is %d/%d/%d\n",d.da_day,d.da_mon,d.da_year);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int main()` maybe?

Comment: The `std::chrono` namespace has a whole suite of date and time functions.

Comment: Stop using Turbo C++, period.

Comment: Please, please, pick a compiler that isn't 20 years out of date. Learning with ancient tools is going to be a serious hindrance to you.

Comment: @BoBTFish, NickyC: OP is already trying to use a newer compiler.

Comment: Start writing real C++?

Comment: The example here should get you going: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct analogy to `getdate` is `time` + `localtime`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */

int main ()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    time ( &rawtime );

    tm * const ptm = localtime ( &rawtime );

    printf("Current system date is %d/%d/%d\n",
             ptm->tm_day,ptm->_mon+1,ptm->tm_year+1900);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, for a more "C++" style approach, look up `std::chrono`